# MongoDb - Group inside push

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I'm trying to get a list of stations traveled to from an origin station, group and count how many times each station was traveled to. So far I have

```
db.skytrain.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: {Origin: "$start_station.station_name"},
Destination: {$push: "$end_station.station_name"}
}}

])
```

which gives me a full list of destinations from each origin station, but I'm not sure how to further group and count, I've tried the following

```
db.skytrain.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: {Origin: "$start_station.station_name"},
Destination: {$push: "$end_station.station_name", count{$sum: 1}}
}}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
])

db.skytrain.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: {Origin: "$start_station.station_name"},
Destination: {$push: "$end_station.station_name"}, count{$sum: 1}
}}

])
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

db.skytrain.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: {Origin: "$start_station.station_name"},
Destination: {$group: {$push: "$end_station.station_name", count{$sum: 1}}}
}}

])
```

and many other combinations, but I either get an error, or a result other than what I'm looking for. Admittedly I'm new to noSQL. The screenshot below shows the current output, it lists every station traveled to as a sublist of every origin station, but I want to group and count that sublist by station... Hope that makes sense

[image: Screen]

Comment: Could you also add sample data and expected result to the question?

Comment: Hi Sarslan, thanks for the reply, I have added more info to my original post